# Unable to append second element with PHP DOMDocument

Tags: php, domdocument

I'm trying to pass a block of HTML through PHP's DOMDocument to refactor `<img>` elements inline with: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

For each `<img>` I'm trying to insert a refactored duplicate, then wrap the original in `<noscript>` tags for a non-JS fallback.

**Example:**

Input:

`<img src="img/example.jpg" width="640" heigh="480">`

Output:

`<img class="lazy" src="img/grey.gif" data-original="img/example.jpg"  width="640" heigh="480"><noscript><img src="img/example.jpg" width="640" heigh="480"></noscript>`

I have the wrapping working and the new element also constructs correctly. The problem is that the second `appendChild` (below) doesn't work and I can't figure out why. Can anyone provide a solution?

I have the following code:

```
$noScript = $dom->createElement('noscript');
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $image) {
    $src = $image->getAttribute('src');
    $alt = $image->getAttribute('alt');
    $title = $image->getAttribute('title');
    $style = $image->getAttribute('style');

    $newImage = $dom->createElement('img');
    $newImage->setAttribute('class', 'lazy');
    $newImage->setAttribute('data-original', $src);
    $newImage->setAttribute('src', '/images/whitespace.gif');
    if ($style) $newImage->setAttribute('style', $style);
    if ($alt) $newImage->setAttribute('alt', $alt);
    if ($title) $newImage->setAttribute('title', $title);

    $noScriptClone = $noScript->cloneNode();
    $image->parentNode->replaceChild($noScriptClone, $image);
    $noScriptClone->appendChild($image);
    $noScriptClone->parentNode->appendChild($newImage);
}
return $dom->saveHTMLExact();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did solve this (in a roundabout kind of way) but forgot to post my solution - until now.

I ended up using [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) which worked out really well.

```
function lazyLoadImages($source = '') {
  $qp = htmlqp($source);
  foreach ($qp->find('img') as $image) {
    $src = $image->attr('src');
    $alt = $image->attr('alt');
    $title = $image->attr('title');
    $style = $image->attr('style');
    $class = $image->attr('class');
    $image->wrap('<noscript/>')->parent('noscript')->after('<img src="/images/whitespace.gif" data-original="' . $src . '" style="' . trim($style) . '"' . ($alt ? ' alt="' . $alt . '"' : '') . ($title ? ' title="' . $title . '"' : '') . ' class="lazy' . ($class ? ' ' . $class : '') . '" />');
  }
  $content = preg_replace(array("/<\?xml.*?\?>/si", "/<\!DOCTYPE.*?>/", "!<(/)?body>!si", "!<(/)?html>!si"), '', $qp->writeSnippet());
  return $content;
}
```